# Function from open subset to $\mathbb{R}$ at $x_0$ has $f'(x_0) = 0$ and $f''(x_0) < 0$, then $f$ attains a maximum.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ be open, and let $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable at some $x_0 \in U$. Show that if $f'(x_0)=0$ and $f''(x_0)<0$, then there exists $\delta>0$ so that $f$ attains a maximum on $B(x_0, \delta)$ at $x_0$.

---

I presume I'd have to use Rolle's theorem in some way but I have no idea how to implement it. The negative second derivative implies the that $x_0$ is a maximum though I don't know how to use only analysis (not calculus) to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Because the second derivative is negative, there is some $\delta$ so that $f'(x)<0$ for $x_0<x<x_0+\delta$ and $f'(x)>0$ for $x_0>x>x_0-\delta$.  Then $x_0$ is a maximum of $f$ in $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$ by Rolle's theorem (if $f(x_1)=f(x_0)$ then there's some $x_2$ between the two with $f'(x_2)=0$, impossible).

Answer (score 0):

If $f \in C^2(U)$ ,  $f′(x_0)=0$ and $f′′(x_0)<0$, then there is $ \delta >0$ such that $f′′(t)<0$ for all $t \in B(x_0, \delta)$.

For $x \in B(x_0, \delta)$ we have, by Taylor:

$f(x)=f(x_0)+\frac{1}{2}f''(t)(x-x_0)^2$ for some $t \in B(x_0, \delta)$, thus

$f(x)<f(x_0)$ if $x \in B(x_0, \delta)$ and $x \ne x_0$

Comment: Unfortunately we only know that $f$ is twice differentiable at $x_0$ and not at any other point (including the ones in the ball) so this proof wouldn't work.